# Simple example multiplexer usage

Tags: multiplexer

I'm new at multiplexing with arduino (I use arduino from some years), and -as title says- I'd like to learn. I'm trying to build an expandible system with 3 sensors, and I'd like to use a 74hc595b1 to link them, leaving some pins free. My first question is: is It possible? And second, can you kindly link me a simple -but very simple- example about multiplexers in arduino? Thankyou!

Comment: What kind of sensors? Also, the 74hc595b1 is a shift register, not a multiplexer.

Comment: I have a hc-sr04 sensor and a temperature sensor (I think a P-MOS)

Comment: Neither of those are suitable for using with a shift register

Comment: So, how can I do with more sensors?

Comment: Get a board with more pins, or use two boards and make them communicate with each other.

Comment: And so -and sorry for the many questions- i can use a multiplexer just for output? i.e. a 7segments display?

Comment: You can use a ***shift register*** for that, yes. A multiplexer is a ***very*** different thing and is ***not*** what you have there.

Comment: i just bought an 8-IO adding PCF8574T for less than $1.50USD, look into it. If you want good analog IO, a 16-bit ADS1115 adds 4 hi-res input for about $2.50....

Comment: There's a detailed explanation of multiplexer use in [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/36931/31794).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For connecting 8 analog devices to an Arduino, using only 3 Arduino pins, look at say a 4051 multiplexer IC: [4051 example](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67004/how-do-i-extend-the-number-of-analog-input-pins-available-to-me)